# changing startup page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I added one new new page to my dotnetnuke application,now i want to cahnge my newly created page as default startup page for my dotnetnuke website. Please tell me how to change the page..

Answer (score 2):

Log into your portal, go to Admin > Site Settings > Advanced Settings, and find your page in the Home Page dropdown.